# fast global search using jsf, spring, hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, annotations

The project, on which i am working,is integrated on spring3, hibernate, jsf2.0, also using annotations.The project have different modules and each module have different processes and each process contains Master Details screens.In module, All Processes are dependent/related to one another from top to bottom.Custom search is developed throughout the module in each process.Now on the project requirements,it needs to develop global search throughout the Module.Each module has 90 database tables with huge data inside and there is a "Item Table" which is used throughout the Module(all processes details screens revised that item). Through global search user will enter an item and search it.Searching should returns all processes details in result(output) within seconds. As i already told above that each table also have huge data inside.What should be the mechanism to develop fast searching feature to avoid from System hanging or going down.

```
Overview:

    Searching Flow:Suppose Item No:1234--> Module-->Each process -->Each process details-->items details found
    Developing Tools: eclipse-jee-juno-win32 , Microsoft SQL Server.
```

I request every one who view this question please help me to share perfect solution as i get correct answer.I will apply correct answer in project.

Comment: One possibility is to use dedicated search engine / index like Elasticsearch. http://www.elasticsearch.org/

Comment: this way is not working